# 2 users updating a record at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know what will happen in the following hypothetical situation. Let's say two teachers give the exact same class to the same students, they both want to update the student's, bob's, grades. Bob's current average is 60%, teacher 1 wants to update his average with a test where he got 70% and teacher 2 wants to update his average with a test where he scored 40%.

So in the 1 to a million chance that the 2 teachers hit the update button simultaneously, precisely to the split-second exactly at the same time, what will happen? Will it give an error message, does php or mysql magically queue updates, will only the first score update bob's average and the second user get an error?

Edit: My concern is that the second user must get the value after the first user edited the values, I was thinking of fetching the record then doing the calculations in php and then updating the record again, but in this situation how can I ensure that the second user fetches a value of 65% and not 60%, can this be done with transactions?

Comment: use the transactions! In MySQL world the InnoDB support full ACID, read more information here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: Does transactions queue queries before it commits to them?

Comment: If there are chances, sql transactions must be used. All the databases systems autolock the rows or tables until the first query is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both will go through and the last one to be processed will be the new value. Due to consistency guarantees from the database system you won't get corrupt data, but because this is a calculated value you may get *wrong*  data.

I suspect that this average is a calculated value based on data in some other table. If that's the case, do all the work in one transaction. Add the new test score to the table, and let the database both calculate the average and insert the result directly into the second table. That way, either the result will be guaranteed to be correct *or*  the transaction will fail. This requires a storage engine with transaction support (e.g., InnoDB).

Answer (score 3):

They cannot run the action at the same time, there will always be a small difference because it is physically impossible for the machine to write the same information at the same time. Might be a matter of microseconds or smaller, but the difference will be there.

One of the usual solutions is to add data like that in your `WHERE` clause, and check whether an update has been done:

```
UPDATE students SET `avg` = '70' WHERE id=<some-id> AND `avg` = '60';
```

However, stuff like *averages* are usually best not updated this way: have a seperate student-scores table, and calculate the average of those records per student yourself (you can still *'cache'* it in the students table if you like).

Answer (score 1):

The database will update the row sequentially. One of the queries will be run first, lock the row (or sometimes table - depending on the query) and the next query will be queued until the first one is finished.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get any trouble if the operation is atomic. And your INSERT is. Both INSERT will be executed.

Beware of non atomical operations though !

That's where Transactions hop in: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_transaction

Answer (score 1):

Pessimistic locking and transactions are only half of the story here. The database will take out a row lock, but that only ensures that anyone trying to modify the same row must wait until the current transaction completes. The case I would want to prevent is:

1. Teacher a views the assignment and sees no grade.
2. Teacher b views the assignment and sees no grade.
3. Teacher a assigns the grade 70.
4. Teacher b assigns the grade 40.

It is very likely that b did not mean to override a. Your best protection is some form of optimistic locking. You see this in wikis when two people make simultaneous edits. The later submitter must confirm the edit because it might accidentally reverse the earlier submitter's changes. In the grading case, you could add the old grade that was displayed to the user in the where clause, then assert that the update changed one row.

```
UPDATE GRADES SET SCORE=70 WHERE NAME='Jim' AND SCORE=0;
```